# Mutiple Masters for Spark and Zookeeper HA

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup multi master spark for High Availability in Standalone mode.

I have 6 node cluster: 6 workers and  2 masters are available.

All of the 6 workers are showing up on Master 1 UI, where as spark master 2 doesnt have any workers listed? Do i need to start the workers on master 2 also?

Or will ZooKeeper switch those worked to master 2 in case of failure of master 1?

One more thing is i have ZooKeeper setup for kafka on same nodes. Now do i need to install ZooKeeper separately for Spark? Does the new ZooKeeper needs to have different port number from Kafkas ZooKeeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will zookeeper switch those worked to master 2 in case of failure of master 1?

Yes, it will. If you've [set up everything properly](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#standby-masters-with-zookeeper) you can kill master 1, wait for a couple of seconds and you'll see master 2 taking over and see all the available worker resources move there.

> Now do I need to install zookeeper separately for Spark?

This is a design decision your team needs to make, but generally ZooKeeper is designed to be a centralized configuration for multiple applications. In our production environment we have a single ZooKeeper cluster connected to both Kafka and Spark.

Comment: I have zookeeper.properties set as below in kafka folders clientPort=2181
server.1=zookeeper1:2888:3888
server.2=zookeeper2:2888:3888
server.3=zookeeper3:2888:3888.How to configure spark and zookeeper? can i just the modify the zookeeper.properties file that was configured for kafka and paste it to spark/conf folder? Does zookeeper for spark and kafka use same port number?

Comment: You don't need to manually configure ZooKeeper at all. All you need to is follow the link I've provided as to how configure Spark.

Comment: Thank you Yuval. I have successfully setup HA for spark with 2 masters. Will there be any data loss (spark streaming with kafka) while spark job is being switched between masters? Any issues while it is being switched?

Comment: @AKC How are you running your spark job. Cluster mode or Client mode?